MPI failed to run on more than one host with OFI poll failed error
I am using MPICH 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 24.04 testing with the small program cpi that calculates the value of pi using MPI. I can start on host1 to run cpi on either host1 or host2 alone and I can start on host2 to run cpi on either host2 or host1 alone. The problem occurs only if I try to use both host1 and host2 together.
This is done using, for example, the command
mpiexec -host host1,host2 -n 2 cpi
then it ends with the error
Abort(77718927) on node 1: Fatal error in internal_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
internal_Init(48306).............: MPI_Init(argc=0x7ffdb68e7fec, argv=0x7ffdb68e7fe0) failed
MPII_Init_thread(265)............:
MPIR_init_comm_world(34).........:
MPIR_Comm_commit(823)............:
MPID_Comm_commit_post_hook(222)..:
MPIDI_world_post_init(660).......:
MPIDI_OFI_init_vcis(842).........:
check_num_nics(891)..............:
MPIR_Allreduce_allcomm_auto(4726):
MPIC_Sendrecv(306)...............:
MPIC_Wait(91)....................:
MPIR_Wait(780)...................:
MPIR_Wait_state(737).............:
MPIDI_progress_test(134).........:
MPIDI_OFI_handle_cq_error(791)...: OFI poll failed  (ofi_events.c:793:MPIDI_OFI_handle_cq_error:Input/output error)
Abort(77718927) on node 0: Fatal error in internal_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
internal_Init(48306).............: MPI_Init(argc=0x7ffcb5b28adc, argv=0x7ffcb5b28ad0) failed
MPII_Init_thread(265)............:
MPIR_init_comm_world(34).........:
MPIR_Comm_commit(823)............:
MPID_Comm_commit_post_hook(222)..:
MPIDI_world_post_init(660).......:
MPIDI_OFI_init_vcis(842).........:
check_num_nics(891)..............:
MPIR_Allreduce_allcomm_auto(4726):
MPIC_Sendrecv(306)...............:
MPIC_Wait(91)....................:
MPIR_Wait(780)...................:
MPIR_Wait_state(737).............:
MPIDI_progress_test(134).........:
MPIDI_OFI_handle_cq_error(791)...: OFI poll failed  (ofi_events.c:793:MPIDI_OFI_handle_cq_error:Input/output error)
Has anyone any experience in dealing with this?
Thanks!
